# Redirect old domain to new domain, including /en/

Tags: django, nginx, redirect

Little stuck but I'm trying to redirect an old domain name to a new domain, which is working to a point. However, we have a long list of URLs from our old website (using the old domain). Which have /en/ appended at the end.

So the issue is when I link olddomain.com/en/old-url to newdomain.com/new-url it throws a 404 as it's not picking up the '/en/'. I've compiled a long list of 301 redirects inside the Django admin, but they don't include the '/en/'. Which is where the issue is. Ideally, I want to add something to my nginx config that tells the domain to redirect even if the /en/ is included.

So Far I have something like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name olddomain.co.uk www.olddomain.co.uk olddomain.co.uk/en/
    return 301 https://www.newdomain.co.uk$request_uri;

}

server {
HTTPS
server_name olddomain.co.uk www.olddomain.co.uk olddomain.co.uk/en/;
    #return 301 https://www.newdomain.co.uk$request_uri;
    listen 443;
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/en/` is part of the URI and does not belong in the `server_name`. If the original request contains `/en/`, then the `$request_uri` variable will also include it. So `olddomain.co.uk/en/foo` is already redirecting to `www.newdomain.co.uk/en/foo`. So I am not sure what problem you are trying to fix.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll just have to manage redirects with /en/ and without as separate links.